# Hide the number 0 when woocommerce cart is empty

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

Hi i bought a woocommerce theme for my online shop. The theme shows in general the number 0 next to the cart icon, so even if it's empty. How can i hide the 0 and only show the amount of products when their is something in the cart? For example, when cart is empty, it should be only the icon and if i put their 2 items inside, it should show the icon an number

That's the code that i found in the theme files:

```
       <a itemprop="url" <?php tonda_select_class_attribute( $dropdown_cart_icon_class ); ?> href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>">
        <span class="qodef-cart-icon"><?php echo tonda_select_get_dropdown_cart_icon_html(); ?></span>
        <span class="qodef-cart-number"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d', '%d', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count, 'tonda'), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count); ?></span>
    </a>
```

Comment: I don't think that that is a bug. I've seen it a lot, where 0 is next to the icon!

Comment: But `tonda_select_class_attribute()` and `tonda_select_get_dropdown_cart_icon_html()` are custom functions, and nobody can guess their code, if you don't provide it, as your theme is commercial. Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**".*… You need to provide all the necessary code to make it testable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of items in an if statement. If the number is more than 0, show the number.

```
<a itemprop="url" <?php tonda_select_class_attribute( $dropdown_cart_icon_class ); ?> 
    href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>">
    <span class="qodef-cart-icon"><?php echo tonda_select_get_dropdown_cart_icon_html(); ?></span>
    <?php if( WC()->cart->cart_contents_count > 0 ) : ?>
        <span class="qodef-cart-number"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d', '%d', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count, 'tonda'), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?
</a>
```